# How to achieve fault tolerance with logstash forwarder?

Tags: tomcat, logstash, logstash-forwarder, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am using Logstash Forwarder to process tomcat logs.

My logstash forwarder config file contains :

```
 "files": [
{
  "paths": [ "/usr/share/tomcat/impression_logs/impressions.log" ]
}]
```

I am using log rotation so it will archive log file to different folder after some time or when file size exceeds 1MB.

If logstash-forwarder is down for few minutes logs are getting archived and it does not process those logs.

I am using monit to monitor logstash forwarder, but still there is chance of 
losing logs.

Is there a way to achieve fault tolerance with logstash forwarder?

Comment: How is a logfile rotated? Is it copied to a new file followed by a truncation of the original file? Or is the original file renamed?

Comment: We use log4j to rotate log file. If this file exceeds a size of 1MB, it will be renamed and  replaced by a new impressions.log file

Answer (score 0):

I am using logstash-forwarder to send all logs from 4-5 tomcats per server and it's working fine and no logs are lost. May be you just need to set "dead time" not to 24 hours, for me it is 10 minutes. Cause if forwarder will fall and then will be started afer more than a couple of hours you can get high loading when it starts to send all logs for 24 hours.